# Wiris demo for generating eps file with mathml

Tags: mathml, wiris

As given in the [example](https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/mathtype_web/sdk-api/services#examples) I was able to run the get the eps file but when I try to pass my own MathML formula to generate the eps I always get a 500 error, Here is my MathML

```
<math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨><mi>§#949;</mi><mi>§#966;</mi><mstyle displaystyle=¨false¨><munderover><mo>§#8721;</mo><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></munderover></mstyle></math>
```

[image]

But when I try to send this MathML to the eps generate it gives me an error can someone help me if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by URL encoding the entire MathML string and passing it to the `mml` parameter.